# C++ OpenGL window only tracks background

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

Anyone knows why this happens when trying to generate a simple square in OpenGL?

I am using the following source code from the book **Computer Graphics Through OpenGL**: *From Theory to Experiments*.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////          
// square.cpp
//
// Stripped down OpenGL program that draws a square.
// 
// Sumanta Guha.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

// Drawing (display) routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   // Clear screen to background color.
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   // Set foreground (or drawing) color.
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   // Draw a polygon with specified vertices.
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(80.0, 20.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(80.0, 80.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(20.0, 80.0, 0.0);
   glEnd();

   // Flush created objects to the screen, i.e., force rendering.
   glFlush(); 
}

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void) 
{
   // Set background (or clearing) color.
   glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
   // Set viewport size to be entire OpenGL window.
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);

   // Set matrix mode to projection.
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

   // Clear current projection matrix to identity.
   glLoadIdentity();

   // Specify the orthographic (or perpendicular) projection, 
   // i.e., define the viewing box.
   glOrtho(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);

   // Set matrix mode to modelview.
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

   // Clear current modelview matrix to identity.
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key) 
   {
  // Press escape to exit.
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

// Main routine: defines window properties, creates window,
// registers callback routines and begins processing.
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{  
   // Initialize GLUT.
   glutInit(&argc, argv);

   // Set display mode as single-buffered and RGB color.
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 

   // Set OpenGL window size.
   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

   // Set position of OpenGL window upper-left corner.
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); 

   // Create OpenGL window with title.
   glutCreateWindow("square.cpp");

   // Initialize.
   setup(); 

   // Register display routine.
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene); 

   // Register reshape routine.
   glutReshapeFunc(resize);  

   // Register keyboard routine.
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);

   // Begin processing.
   glutMainLoop(); 

   return 0;  
}
```

I've been trying for the longest time...

For more details here:

The screen opens displaying only the background, if you drag it along, it will then proceed to track the background, and this is the result of moving the window to the bottom and then moving it up to the original position again. I've tested the same source code on a linux machine, and it works fine... :(

EDIT: I have tried using glutSwapBuffers() and that didn't seem to work either.

[image]

Comment: Are you running on Windows Vista or newer? This could be a DWM compositor issue associated with rendering to the front-buffer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running W7... What exactly does that mean? And does that mean that there's no fix for this?

Comment: Okay, this is going to be complicated to explain :) Basically, with Windows Vista and later windows are drawn into offscreen surfaces and the operating system uses a copy of the backbuffer when it "paints" the windows. By having a copy of the backbuffer available, it can do the fancy pants live window previews and other effects that did not exist prior to Windows XP. To correct this, you either need to draw to the backbuffer or use double buffering and swap buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows Vista and newer Windows operating systems, there is a component known as the `Desktop Window Manager` (DWM) which has a special mode called "Desktop Composition" that draws windows into offscreen buffers and then composites them. It does this to provide new visual effects such as live window previews in the Alt+Tab screen.

A consequence of this new architecture is that you cannot draw single buffered applications (*in windowed mode anyway*) the same way you could in Windows XP (or in Windows Vista+ with Desktop Composition disabled). In a nutshell, the DWM uses a copy of your render context's back buffer for composition. You should switch to double buffered drawing.

To use double buffered drawing in GLUT, you would use `GLUT_DOUBLE` instead of `GLUT_SINGLE` in your call to `glutInitDisplayMode (...)`. Additionally, you need to replace your calls to `glFlush (...)` with `glutSwapBuffers (...)`.

Comment: I tired using gluSwapBuffers() instead of glFlush() and that didn't seem to work either :( Is the end solution really to switch operating systems?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: You also need to pass `GLUT_DOUBLE` to `glutInitDisplayMode (...)` to establish a double buffered render context. And no, there is absolutely no need to switch operating systems. Single buffered rendering is something you should not be using in the first place, this just forces the issue on you :P

Comment: OMG! It worked! I have no idea what happened, but it worked! Adding GLUT_DOUBLE. Umm.. so I kinda want to understand what's happening here, what exactly did GLUT_DOUBLE do?  I'm so thankful for this. Five hours! THANK YOU!

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: `GLUT_DOUBLE` made it so that your GPU uses two buffers when it draws. There is a `front buffer` that it renders all of your commands to (this buffer is constantly being updated as individual polygons are drawn) and a `back buffer` that contains a finished copy of your last frame. When you finish drawing commands for your current frame, you let the driver know by doing something called "swapping buffers" and it will copy/exchange the contents of the front buffer with the back buffer when it finishes. DWM always wants a **COMPLETELY** rendered image, so it uses the back buffer.

Comment: I think I'm understanding this a little bit better now. Thank you @Andon M. Coleman I really appreciate the time you've taken to answer my question.

Comment: I just realized I wrote the explanation about front/back backwards. Regardless what you call them, one is always finished (presented in D3D terminology) and the other is being drawn to. Since there are triple buffers and the method for swapping varies (copy/exchange) it's probably best to think of them as 1,2,3...n and acknowledge that only one of them is displayed at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a call to `glutSwapBuffers();` at the end of `drawScene` and removing `GLUT_SINGLE` from `glutInitDisplayMode`. Single-buffer mode has all sorts of compatibility issues. On Windows it uses the software rasterizer which is VERY slow and has even more issues.

If that doesn't work, try clearing the depth buffer by changing `glClear` to `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` and `glClearcolor` to `glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`.

Also, this example uses legacy OpenGL, which is significantly slower than modern OpenGL and has many other problems. Unless you are using a GPU that's more than a decade old, you have zero reason to use it. Technically, modern GPUs aren't even required to support it. If you need a good modern OpenGL tutorial, http://open.gl is a good one. Just look for an OpenGL 2.1 (or later) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @ECrownofFire, but this did not work either :(. The only reason I'm following this is because my class uses this textbook and I'm following by example.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat Ah, well that's unfortunate. Legacy OpenGL does not carry over very well.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: That book is actually quite a good one, despite the early samples using legacy OpenGL. I am familiar with the book, and it makes a great textbook with its heavy focus on theory rather than API. You are fortunate to have a curriculum that uses such a good book, just be aware that some of the simpler samples will not run right on modern computers -- that's true of virtually all OpenGL `textbooks`.