# VS 2012 Build/Shader trouble

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I'm fairly new to Visual studios and C++ as well. I've been trying to get the Sierpinski Gasket example from Interactive Computer Graphics A Top-Down Approach with OpenGL by Ed Angels, specifically the Chapter 2 Example 1 Visual C++ Project, and I've ran into to some problems that I can't seem to solve or find a solution to. The problem I have is when I run it in VS2012 the window immediately closes with error something along the lines of it couldn't find vshader21.glsl. When I run it from the 6E Test.exe in the debug folder it opens fine, creates a window but it doesn't show any of the triangles, just a blank white box. I have downloaded the latest versions of GLEW and freeglut and I'm positive I put everything in the right place.

The example project includes: Angel.h, vec.h, mat.h, CheckError.h, example1.cpp, InitShader.cpp, vshader21.glsl, and fshader21.glsl

I believe the error is coming from the example1.cpp with the line GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader21.glsl", "fshader21.glsl" ); not finding the files ut i have added both the .glsl to the debug folder and changed the path to go to the debug folder in the Working Directory of the project properties. Any Suggestions or solutions as to how i can fix this?

```
#include "Angel.h"

const int NumPoints = 5000;

void
init( void )
{

    vec2 points[NumPoints];

    // Specifiy the vertices for a triangle
    vec2 vertices[3] = {
        vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), vec2( 0.0, 1.0 ), vec2( 1.0, -1.0 )
    };

    // Select an arbitrary initial point inside of the triangle
    points[0] = vec2( 0.25, 0.50 );

    // compute and store N-1 new points
    for ( int i = 1; i < NumPoints; ++i ) {
        int j = rand() % 3;   // pick a vertex at random

        // Compute the point halfway between the selected vertex
        //   and the previous point
        points[i] = ( points[i - 1] + vertices[j] ) / 2.0;
    }

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader21.glsl", "fshader21.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                           BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
}

void
display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );     // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, NumPoints );    // draw the points
    glFlush();
}

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key ) {
    case 033:
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    // If you are using freeglut, the next two lines will check if 
    // the code is truly 3.2. Otherwise, comment them out

     glutInitContextVersion( 3, 1 );
     glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );

    glutCreateWindow( "Sierpinski Gasket" );

    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE** this is what it tells me when I press F5 to run it.
my version of GLEW is 1.10.0 and freeglut is 2.8.1-1

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\Documents\6E test\Debug\6E test.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\Documents\6E test\Debug\freeglut.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Robert\Documents\6E test\Debug\glew32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig7icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'

'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The program '[6244] 6E test.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Comment: Why are you trying to use [`#version 150` shaders on a 3.1 context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_%28GLSL%29#OpenGL_and_GLSL_versions)?

Comment: Definitely check some version numbers.  Can you capture any error output when you compile the shaders?  Does InitShader() do that?  After that, I'm having a hard time understanding how you're attempting to generate vertices - have you been able to render a plain triangle?  I might guess at something like winding if your shaders are compiling fine.

Comment: @genpfault : i was told  that it shouldve just ran after downloading evrything and putting it all in the right place. IM sorry I'm new to visual studios and GLSL.

Comment: @Max Feldkamp : i updated with i think everything you asked for. i have used another example that has succesfully generated a triangle but not with this particular example.

Comment: Thanks!  The debug info indicates it's nothing on the CPU side (it's finding the shaders fine - a good step), but when you load your shaders via InitShaders(), are you getting any output (i.e. in your test console) to indicate your graphics card isn't compiling the shaders correctly or not?  If you can't see anything, do a simple std::cout << "Program ID: " << program; right after you call InitShaders().  If it says 0 - that's where your problem is and you should look at the shader code.

Comment: @Max Feldkamp : After I add that where would it say 0 if it was saying 0 in the first place. Should it be good exactly as written or do I need to change it? As well idk if it helps or not but when I run it, in the window that pops up it gives me "vshader21.glsl failed to compile: ERROR: 0:7: '<' : syntax error syntax error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use single-buffered windowed drawing in newer versions of Microsoft Windows, with *Desktop Composition* enabled. Even after you get your shader loading mechanism working correctly, you are going to run into a much bigger issue, where the ouput is not visible. In fact judging by your problem description I think you already are encountering this issue.

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477852) for a more detailed explanation of the problem and the solution.