# Is glutSwapBuffer command required to get background color?

Tags: opengl

I didn't understand the functionality of glutSwapBuffer properly. In my code if I don't use the glutSwapBuffer than no background color came in window and it remain transparent, capturing whatever is there in its background. I think that the background color is actually assigned by glClearColor, than how come without using glutSwapBuffer I didn't get any background color.

Comment: All the opengl functions *including glClear* only update the back buffer. 
Once you finished drawing you swap your drawing onto the front buffer.

Comment: ... assuming you've requested [`GLUT_DOUBLE`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node12.html)

Comment: glClearColor only selects the color, the framebuffer gets cleared to by a `glClear` call with the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` set.

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up over and over, I think what you are describing is actually what happens when you draw exclusively into the front-buffer in a compositing window manager.

Without swapping buffers, it does not draw your window correctly, so the window appears transparent. Double buffering is required for compositing window managers and it seems it is also required for many hybrid integrated/discrete GPU implementations (e.g. nVIDIA Optimus). In short, there is no real reason to use single-buffered rendering on a desktop platform these days.

To be certain, does your situation resemble this? This screenshot shows what happens when a window that only uses single-buffering is moved in a compositing window manager.

[image]

If so, a more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477852).

Answer (score 1):

opengl usually is configured to use double buffering.

You first draw to one buffer... then Swap it with the second and present it on the screen.
Without calling glutSwapBuffer you will not see anything and it is correct behavior.

[about double (and more) buffering in opengl](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/smooth_rotation.html)