# openGL window content copies what was behind it

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a simple square, but the window content copies what was behind it, a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCVLN.png), the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void Draw(void){
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
                   
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
       glVertex2i(100,150);
       glVertex2i(100,100);

       glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
       glVertex2i(150,100);
       glVertex2i(150,150);               
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Init(void){   
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(400,350);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);

    glutCreateWindow("Window");

    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);

    Init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I compile with this command:
`g++ main.cpp -lglu32 -lglut32 -lopengl32 -o open.exe`

My computer info:

- GPU: GMA 3150
- CPU: atom D525
- RAM: 4GB
- openGL: 1.40v
- 64 BITS

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477852/c-opengl-window-only-tracks-background) I replaced `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)` to `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE)` and also replaced `glFlush()` to `glutSwapBuffers()` , however nothing changes.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a call to `glutInit(..)` before the call to `glutCreateWindow(..)`? Also see the SO post you linked to for replacing other glut call.

Comment: @Yun it's true, i'll change the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it! explanation:

1. Change MinGW to TDM-gcc
2. Change Glut to Freeglut
3. Set compiler to 64bits, `g++ **-m64** main.cpp **-lfreeglut** -lglu32 -lopengl32 -o open.exe`
4. Solve code problem

new code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void Draw(void){
    //*
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,400,0,350,-1,1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //*
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1.0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
       glVertex2i(100,150);
       glVertex2i(100,100);

       glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
       glVertex2i(150,100);
       glVertex2i(150,150);               
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//Remove Init function

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(400,350);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);

    glutCreateWindow("Window");

    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

*For future readers with the same problem, use the libraries according to your compiler architecture! (32bits or 64bits)